# What device do I need to project a laser to point at a specific location?

Tags: laser

I'm searching for a (commercial) projector that just projects a single laser point into the world (e.g. using two moving mirrors). However, I'm struggling because I'm not sure what such a thing is called. I either find area projectors that use lasers, party equipment or laser pointers.

What is the name for such a device?

Comment: What's your application? Are you looking to purchase a finished solution or are you okay with DIY?

Comment: I want to check if you can build some kind of Human Robot Interface with the system. And I'd rather buy something as I currently have more funding than time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying mechanism used by high performance laser painting devices is usually a *galvo* (Galvanometer scanner, Laser Galvanometer or Mirror Galvanometer).

High performance galvos, like this one from scanlab are essential to the  laser [micro-machining](http://www.scanlab.de/en/applications/micromachining) (drilling, cutting, marking) industries:

[image: Scanlab mirror galvanometer from Wikipedia]

Their cost and performance may significantly exceed your requirements however. These are designed to position themselves in microseconds, to sub-micron (near field) accuracy.

<sub>I have no association with Scanlab, but I worked for many years in the laser micro-machining industry and they are the products I'm most familiar with.</sub>

Comment: +1, in 2D cutting applications, using a galvo to move the laser is orders of magnitude faster compared to a CNC based movement of the laser. The reason is that the mirror is very light and the only mass that has to be moved.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. I just ordered a preconfigured pair with controller, so that I just have to provide analog Input signals for the two mirrors (http://www.mylaserpage.de/images/Litrack.jpg).